# JavaScript: How do I add a class on a 'resize' event after removing it?

Tags: javascript, css

I am adding an event listener to the window to listen for the **resize** event. Essentially I'd like to remove the `'center'` class when the width of the browser falls below 768px and then add it back when we are above 768px.

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var width = 0,
        doc = document,
        div = doc.getElementsByTagName('div'), i;
    if (window.innerHeight) {
        width = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (doc.documentElement && doc.document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        width = doc.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (doc.body) {
        width = doc.body.clientWidth;
    }
    if (width < 768) {
        for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
            div[i].classList.remove('center');
        }
    } else {
        div[i].classList.add('center');
    }
}, false);
```

It removes it correctly but upon checking the console, I immediately get this error. Not sure why it would log that error from the onset...

`index.html:591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined(…)`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you simply using CSS Media Queries to do this?

Comment: Why dont you use an `@media query` in CSS?

Comment: You've got `doc.document.documentElement` where it should be `doc.documentElement` and if(window.innerHeight) where it should read window.innerWidth

Comment: Thanks! But that didn't fix it!

Comment: Give a code snippet

Comment: Zero reason to use JS and not CSS media queries.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need js, css only:

```css
.media {
    background-color: blue;
  }
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .media {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="media"> Hello world</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/oYNJGB)

read here about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: This is the way to go. It removes so much complexity.

Comment: Thank you but that would be applicable if you wanted just to change a element. Remove is what I am looking for in this case.

Comment: You may do something like "display:none;" instead of "background-color: red;"

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, this code would not remove the class from the class list, but the effect you are looking for si to be able to have the text be uncentered after ou do a resize. The entire point of media queries in CSS is that you can do these sorts of things without having to rely on javascript. Is there any particular reason you wouldn't want to keep the class on the element, e.g. a script that searches for `.center`-ed elements later on in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up your loop with your if statement.

```
   if (width < 768) {
     for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
         div[i].classList.remove("center");
     }
   } else {
       div[i].classList.add("center");
   }
```

should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  if(width < 768)
       div[i].classList.remove("center");
   } else {
       div[i].classList.add("center");
   }
}
```